# Are UtcNow and Now the same datetime? Do they know they're different?

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, utc

If I run a snippet like:

```
bool areTheyTheSame = DateTime.UtcNow == DateTime.Now
```

what will I get?  Does the DateTime returned know its timezone such that I can compare?

My specific problem is that I'm trying to build a cache-like API.  If it takes a DateTime  AbsoluteExpiration, do I have to enforce that users of my API know whether to give me a UTC time or a timezone-based time?

[Edit] This SO question is extremely relevant to my issue as well: [Cache.Add absolute expiration - UTC based or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688554/cache-add-absolute-expiration-utc-based-or-not)

[Edit] Just to clarify for future readers, the DateTimeKind is what is different.  The Undefined DateTimeKind's are often a problem, which is what you get when you pull one out of a database, for instance.  Set the DateTimeKind in the DateTime constructor...

[Edit] JonSkeet wrote a lovely blog post condemning this behavior and offering a solution: http://noda-time.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you actually try the snippet yourself?

They're different, and a straight comparison doesn't account for the difference, but you can convert local to UTC by calling [`ToUniversalTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime.aspx).

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;

Console.WriteLine(now);                         // 12/07/2010 16:44:16
Console.WriteLine(utcNow);                      // 12/07/2010 15:44:16
Console.WriteLine(now.ToUniversalTime());       // 12/07/2010 15:44:16
Console.WriteLine(utcNow.ToUniversalTime());    // 12/07/2010 15:44:16

Console.WriteLine(now == utcNow);                         // False
Console.WriteLine(now.ToUniversalTime() == utcNow);       // True
Console.WriteLine(utcNow.ToUniversalTime() == utcNow);    // True
```

Comment: I didn't try it, but mostly because I was surprised that the question wasn't on SO already and thought it would be a useful one for people.  And maybe a touch of laziness, but I swear, mostly good intentions! ;)

Comment: The key test I want to see maybe is, is the result of "Console.WriteLine(utcNow.ToUniversalTime() == utcNow);"...

Comment: +1. Additionally, there is a different `DateTimeKind`. There is a `ToLocalTime()` for the other direction. Be careful with `DateTimeKind.Undefined`, these times are always converted (`ToUniversalTime` treats them as local time, `ToLocalTime` as UTC).

Answer (score 2):

Also be wary of taking a local `DateTime` and calling `.ToUniversalTime()` when daylight savings comes around.

See the note in the remarks section here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.touniversaltime.aspx

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.Now returns the system time while DateTime.UtcNow returns the UTC time.