# Why is DateTime.Now.Subtract(DateTime.UtcNow) not (close to) zero?

Tags: c#, .net

If I try:

```
DateTime.Now.Subtract(DateTime.UtcNow)
```

I would expect the result to be very close to zero.  But it's not, instead it's the time zone difference, in my case, -4 hours.  There is a .Kind -- the DateTime KNOWS the timezones are different.  Why doesn't it track this for me?  Is there a flavor of Subtract that DOES use Kind correctly?

(For reference, a good rundown of what each one outputs can be seen at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3229429/237091)

Comment: `DateTime.Now` returns the current system `DateTime`, `DateTime.UtcNow` also applies the timezone conversion to `UTC`. There is no internal representation of timezones with `DateTime`. Perhaps you need `DateTimeOffset`.

Comment: You would get zero if you ran it in Reykjavik, Iceland

Comment: Welcome to the world of `DateTime`. The "kind" is ignored. In .NET 1 it didn't even exist, and it's too late to make things logical now.

Comment: You might want to read [Noda Time - What's wrong with DateTime anyway?](http://noda-time.blogspot.dk/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html).

Comment: @exacerbatedexpert: Nope, it's entirely reasonable to do all kinds of arithmetic on local values. In many cases I'd argue that's *more sensible* than doing it in UTC. The arithmetic shown *here* doesn't make sense, but other arithmetic certainly can.

Comment: @exacerbatedexpert: You can create an invalid local time or even an ambiguous one. Rather than converting local time to UTC before performing arithmetic, I prefer to perform all arithmetic *in* local time, and then *if required* convert to UTC, taking appropriate courses of action if necessary. For example, if a meeting occurs "same time next week" it makes sense to add a week to the *local time*, not UTC (which might end up being at a different local time). See http://noda-time.googlecode.com/hg/docs/userguide/arithmetic.html for my suggestions.

Comment: @exacerbatedexpert: Basically, arithmetic doesn't always want to be performed in terms of *elapsed* time, which is what you get if you always convert to UTC and back again. Given how badly screwed up `DateTime` is, I don't really want to accept "best practices" from the same team who came up with the type ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> There is a .Kind -- the DateTime KNOWS the timezones are different. Why doesn't it track this for me?

Because [`DateTime` is fundamentally broken](http://noda-time.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html) ([and there's more...](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/05/02/more-fun-with-datetime.aspx)). IMO it should complain if you try to subtract a value of one kind from another. But no, it just uses the uninterpreted date/time in each value. Very few operations actually take any notice of the `Kind`, unfortunately. (If you use `TimeZoneInfo`, those operations *do* take notice of it.)

`Kind` was hacked into .NET 2.0; before then a `DateTime` value didn't even know what kind it was - if you used:

```
dt = dt.ToLocalTime().ToLocalTime().ToLocalTime();
```

it would apply the same offset change several times. The BCL team found a couple of spare bits in the binary representation, and used it for `Kind`.

Basically, I feel your pain. Personally I would prefer it if operations like this threw an exception - subtracting a UTC `DateTime` from a local `DateTime` or vice versa makes little sense, IMO.

As an entirely biased plug, you could use [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) which separates the ideas of `Instant`, `LocalDate`, `LocalTime`, `LocalDateTime`, `OffsetDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime`, and doesn't let you perform non-sensical arithmetic. Our aim is to provide a saner API than the BCL one. That doesn't necessarily mean we've succeeded, of course :)

Answer (score 6):

Eh? The `Kind` property does not alter date math. It is only used by time zone methods.

You get exactly the result I would expect you to get. Not sure I understand why you were expecting zero.

Comment: It would make *sense* for it to alter date math though - if only to throw an exception. Fundamentally IMO it doesn't make sense to compare a UTC date/time with a local date/time - or at least you'd want to specify what type of arithmetic you're trying to perform.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Please no more exceptions! We have a hard enough time trying to handle all possible exceptions as it is. Yes, I guess I can see how it could make sense if `Kind` were more strongly implemented.

Comment: @JonathanWood: You shouldn't be trying to handle it - you should fix your code so it doesn't happen! (It would be an `ArgumentException` - which pretty much always means "your code is broken".) You should only be *handling* exceptions which are due to external circumstances etc.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Unfortunately, we are not perfect programmers. And we sometimes don't realize, for example, cases where a value could actually be null. For us, this is the real world. And we have a huge effort making sure all exceptions are dealt with.

Comment: @JonathanWood: We're not perfect which is exactly why exceptions are so good. Because if I'm making a logical error, I'd almost always rather *abort* what I'm doing than keep going with the wrong value. If you don't know whether or not something is null, check for it. If you know it's meant to *not* be null, validate it.

Comment: Or you have a DateTimeUtc type instead, and get the compiler to stop your foolish cross-timezone comparisons early enough that you don't have to catch weird exceptions...

Comment: @ScottStafford: Exactly - it's nice if the type itself indicates the kind of data stored in it :)

Answer (score 0):

Each `DateTime` object represents a local time (as opposed to a UTC time plus a time zone offset).  Even if the `Kind` property equals UTC, it's just storing the local time at the zero time zone.  If it were not a local time, there would be no reason for the `UtcNow` property.

DateTime does not even store the timezone.  If `Kind` equals UTC, then at least you know it's timezone is zero, but if `Kind` is local or unspecified, there is no way of knowing the timezone (the `Kind` property equals `Unspecified` by default).

Therefore, the `Subtract` method cannot incorporate the timezone into its calculation because the timezone is unknown.

Comment: No, please look at the documentation for `DateTime.Kind`.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I understand the `Kind` property.  What did I say that is inaccurate?

Comment: "Each DateTime object represents a local time" - for a DateTime.Kind of Utc, the date/time represented is UTC, not local time. While I suspect I know what you may mean, you've at least expressed it in a very confusing way.

Comment: Somewhat. Not ideal, but then neither is `DateTime` :( `Subtract` certainly *could* take the time zone into account in the `UTC - Local` case, although that would arguably be even worse. As I've said elsewhere, throwing an exception would be better IMO.