# Caching a string for 24 hours

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching

I am trying to cache a string in my .net mvc application for 24 hours.  I am having trouble finding a way to get the cache to expire.  Currently I set the cache using

```
System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache.Default["activeKey"] = "success";
```

I use the cache by calling

```
var activeKey = System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache.Default["activeKey"];
if (activeKey != null && (string) activeKey == "success")
{
    return true;
}
```

However, I am unsure where to go from here as far as cache. I found docs for sliding and absolute cache, but am unsure exactly what to do.

Comment: have you checked this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: `class HackItCacheItem { public DateTime Created {get;set;} public string Value {get;set;} }` if DateTime.Now - Created > TimeSpan.FromDays(1) ...

Comment: I think you need to use `Add()`, it has an overload for CacheItemPolicy

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434284/when-does-asp-net-remove-expired-cache-items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd780614(v=vs.110).aspx) or `AddOrGetExisting` methods are the best you can get. They both have an argument to set the expiration (`absoluteExpiration`).

```
System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache.Default.Add(
    "activeKey",
    "success",
    new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1))
)
```

Comment: With this it says the add method needs 7 parameters

Comment: Not according to the documentation... Weird.

Comment: Ah that would do it, no prefix

Comment: Does this apply the cache for everyone? not just session based.

Comment: Yes, the cache is application-wide.