# System.Web.Caching.Cache doesn't seem to refresh itself on time ? 

Tags: asp.net, caching, system.web.caching

I am using `System.Web.Caching.Cache` in an assembly used by my website.
I have set some key expiration (absolute expiration) to be 10 seconds (just for debugging).
I have also set a callback upon key removal.

The problem is that I see that the cache is getting refreshed after something like 20 seconds and not 10.

I am using `HttpRuntime.Cache` for this.

Any suggestion for why is that happening ?

I would like to show a code sample, which can shed more light:

```
public  void OnUpdate(string key
                      , CacheItemUpdateReason reason
                      , out object expensiveObject
                      , out CacheDependency dependency
                      , out DateTime absoluteExpiration
                      , out TimeSpan slidingExpiration)
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\temp\foo.txt",true))
    {
        sw.WriteLine("Updated Cache at " + DateTime.UtcNow); 
    }
    expensiveObject = 11;
    dependency = null;
    absoluteExpiration = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(3);
    slidingExpiration = Cache.NoSlidingExpiration;
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    log.WriteInfo("Updated Cache", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod());
    Page.Cache.Insert("foo", (object)11, null, DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(10), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, new CacheItemUpdateCallback(OnUpdate));
}
```

Here,  i used `Page.Cache`. The update should be every 3 seconds. Actually it is performed every 40 seconds, as the below printout shows:

`Updated Cache at 1/28/2011 1:38:20 AM
Updated Cache at 1/28/2011 1:38:40 AM
Updated Cache at 1/28/2011 1:39:00 AM
Updated Cache at 1/28/2011 1:39:20 AM
Updated Cache at 1/28/2011 1:39:40 AM
Updated Cache at 1/28/2011 1:40:00 AM
Updated Cache at 1/28/2011 1:40:20 AM
Updated Cache at 1/28/2011 1:40:40 AM
Updated Cache at 1/28/2011 1:41:00 AM
Updated Cache at 1/28/2011 1:41:20 AM
Updated Cache at 1/28/2011 1:41:40 AM
Updated Cache at 1/28/2011 1:42:00 AM
Updated Cache at 1/28/2011 1:42:20 AM
Updated Cache at 1/28/2011 1:42:40 AM`

What could be the problem ?

Comment: Can you post your Cache.Add() statement

Comment: @djeeg: I have just added the question this sample code. You can see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The internal cache expire timer only fires every 20 seconds.

I reflected into `System.Web.Caching.CacheExpires`

But then found it already is on SO

[Changing frequency of ASP.NET cache item expiration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268468/changing-frequency-of-asp-net-cache-item-expiration)

Comment: God Bless You! my friend! you have resolved a whole night without sleeping trying to experiment that thing.
This is just the answer i have been looking for.
The odd thing is that they didn't wrote this on the documentation.
What can we do when we really need the item to be updated after 50 seconds,  for example ?
Basically, what you are saying (and I have read the one you recommended) is that we have to work with the cache in multiples of 20 seconds ? like: 20, 40, 60 and so on ?

Answer (score 0):

You may use PCache class which is implemented inside [PokeIn](http://pokein.codeplex.com) library. The very good thing is, there is no limitation regarding to this class on FREE edition. It has many functionalities and far better than System.Web.Caching.Cache class..

Additionally, there is a sample project on the link. You may change TimerInterval down to 6 sec with PCache.